# Date difference is showing negative value in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In `sqlite` date `difference` is coming `negative`.

```
SELECT (strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s', msl_last_sync_date_time))/60/60 as last_synch_time 
FROM mobi_sync_log 
WHERE my msl_last_sync_date_time is 2015-06-24 10:36:27
```

Please suggest some idea.

Comment: SELECT strftime('now') - strftime(msl_last_sync_date_time) FROM mobi_sync_log; try this

Comment: i want difference in second..

Comment: yes it will come negate then suppose current second is 20 and your time second is "27" so it will show negative value.

Comment: But first i am converting to seconds then doing the difference..I thing in strftime function having some problem.

Answer (score 2):

`now` returns a time in UTC. `2015-06-24 10:36:27` is in the future in UTC considering when you posted the question.

Consider storing all your datetimes in UTC, or add an explicit timezone such as `2015-06-24 10:36:27 +05:30` to them.

Comment: At last your suggestion is working..Thanks laalto.I thing you helped me one more time.